# UPDATE SQL Server Statement only if a specific field is returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do an UPDATE statement, where PRICE_CURRENCY should be populated with a 'U' only when the Initial_Price is populated, it could also be populated with other fields. I have tried to use an EXISTS in the query, but I don't know if that will first check if the Initial_Price is populated then update PRICE_CURRENCY with a 'U'.

```
UPDATE EMIR
SET Price_Currency = 'U' 
from EMIR E
      INNER JOIN CALYPSO cl
        ON e.Internal_ID = cl.Trade_ID
    AND e.Internal_ID_Type = 'CL'
WHERE cl.Initial_Price = 'P'
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

The way the question is asked is a little confusing as the SQL statement in the question doesn't use an EXIST word and there is no explanation regarding the table CALYPSO.

If I understand the question correctly, you want to set the [Price_Currency] field to 'U' only when it has not already been set (I assume it is a nullable field) and when the record in the [CALYPSO] table also has its [Initial_Price] filed set to 'P'.

Try the following query:-

```
UPDATE EMIR
    SET Price_Currency = 'U' 
    FROM EMIR E
         INNER JOIN CALYPSO cl ON e.Internal_ID = cl.Trade_ID
WHERE 
   cl.Initial_Price = 'P' 
   AND E.Price_Currency IS NULL
   AND e.Internal_ID_Type = 'CL'
```